# How to avoid `@KtorExperimentalAPI` propagating everywhere?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I can see that for Ktor 1.4.X, e.g. `io.ktor.config.ApplicationConfig` is marked `@KtorExperimentalAPI`, so that anything that calls it also needs to be marked as `@KtorExperimentalAPI`.

**Edited to add**: In Ktor 1.5.0, `io.ktor.config.ApplicationConfig` no longer requires `@KtorExperimentalAPI`, so by far the best fix for this is to upgrade the Ktor version.

But this is propagating in nature. If I implement a utility function, that needs an application config parameter, and so calls the experimental `Application.environment.config.property(path)` API, this utility function must also must be marked `@KtorExperimentalAPI`. Rince, repeat. Pretty soon, everything in my application is marked `@KtorExperimentalAPI`, because somewhere down in the implementation one (calls an API that)* calls an API that is experimental.

Is there any way to "encapsulate badness": To call the experimental API and do some magic there, so that the `@KtorExperimentalAPI` doesn't become viral and need to spread to the rest of the application?

E.g.:

```kotlin
// I can accept that this perhaps
// needs to be marked @KtorExperimentalAPI 
@KtorExperimentalAPI
fun Application.configProperty(path: String) : String {
    return environment.config.property(path).getString()
}

// But I want to avoid that everything that calls it also
// needs to be marked @KtorExperimentalAPI
fun Application.getFoobarProperty() : String {
    return "${configProperty("foo")}_${configProperty("bar")}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the opt-in to be module-wide using a compiler argument. With that compiler-argument, you don't have to use the annotation anymore. You can read more about it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/opt-in-requirements.html#module-wide-opt-in

If you are using Kotlin-Gradle, add this to your compile-task:

```
kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=io.ktor.util.KtorExperimentalAPI"
```

If you are using Maven, add this configuration to the `kotlin-maven-plugin`:

```
<configuration>
    <args>
        <arg>-Xopt-in=io.ktor.util.KtorExperimentalAPI</arg>
    </args>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link provided in @marstran's answer, I found what I was looking for:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/opt-in-requirements.html#non-propagating-use

It describes how to do what I want:

> In modules that don't expose their own API, such as applications, you can opt in to using APIs without propagating the opt-in requirement to your code. In this case, mark your declaration with @OptIn passing the opt-in requirement annotation as its argument

I ended up with:

```kotlin
// Not @KtorExperimentalAPI, but:
@OptIn(KtorExperimentalAPI::class)
fun Application.configProperty(path: String) : String {
    return environment.config.property(path).getString()
}
```

It does require this to be added to `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
// This is to avoid having to add @KtorExperimentalAPI annotations all over the place
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
}
```